# Is there a way to override the AuthenticationOption.DefaultChallengeScheme on a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

The challenge scheme set on configuring authentication on startup.cs in

```
   services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                ...
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                ...
            })...
```

Have become unsuitable for some of my controllers... Is there a way to override this wihout defining another policy for just those controllers?

The Case i am having is in some controller after a failed authorization i want a user redirected to login an on others i just want a 401 status code returned.

Comment: You can decorate your controller as [AllowAnonymous]. And if you need some other authorization - create a new custom auth attribute.

Comment: I see then peek if the user is authorized and return what i want from there... let me give it a try

Comment: Thanks @BasilKosovan that works i am now returning ```new UnauthorizedResult();``` on api controller... I also added few lines to skip on the ```AllowAnonymous``` attribute